# Using nodejs modules in next.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I facing a problem with nodejs module not working in my nextjs app. Any help would be appreciated

I'm importing it like this
`import {saveAs} from "file-saver";`
[Module not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kl6sr.png)

Comment: Can't reproduce the issue. Make sure you have `file-saver` installed as a dependency in your project.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though you don't have the module installed, to verify it's installed, run the following:

With NPM:

```
npm install file-saver
```

With Yarn:

```
yarn add file-saver
```